# unable to train the randomforest model in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to train my dataset using R. Following is the code that I'll be using

```
functionRankFeatureByImportance <- function(logwine_withoutQuality){
  
  #logwine_withoutQuality$quality<-factor(logwine_withoutQuality$quality)
  # ensure results are repeatable
  set.seed(7)
  # prepare training scheme
  control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
  # train the model
  model <- train(logwine_withoutQuality[,-12],
                 logwine_withoutQuality$quality, method="lvq", preProcess="scale", trControl=control)
  # estimate variable importance
  importance <- varImp(model, scale=FALSE)
  # summarize importance
  print(importance)
  # plot importance
  plot(importance)
}
```

But when using this I'm getting an error like below.

[image]

I'm unable to understand what my error is.

Following is an image of the dataset I'm using

[image]

There aren't any null values in the dataframe.

[image]

[image]

Really appreciate if someone can kindly help me to solve this

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image. No one wants to type it in to test code. Also, it is easy to see that there is more of your error message above what you show. Could you please show the entire error message?  Just a conjecture about your problem: It looks like you took logarithms of the Wine Quality data set. I believe that has some zero values so you will get NA values in your data when you take log(0). That may cause problems here.

Comment: Hi Thanks alot... It was the error... Million thanks